# Undecorated window covers ENTIRE screen

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create an application with a custom title bar (the one with the buttons for minimize, full-screen mode, and close) which is of course, OS-specific. But I only want it on Windows currently.

I did my research and found that I can't change the default OS title bar, but I can remove it by setUndecorated(true). So I did it and found it hid the taskbar and covered the whole screen. I know I can just set a fixed size, but I realized all Windows PCs don't have the same screen size. I want it to work like the setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH), which doesn't work when I do it when undecorated is true...

Is there any way to keep it undecorated, not hide the taskbar, and be fullscreen at the same time? Sorry for my English, my bad :-)

Comment: Could you add what calls you made other than `setUndecorated(true)`? I imagine you used `setFullscreen(true)`, which would fit with what you said about hiding the taskbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JavaFX, you could use [the `Screen` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) to get the visual bounds of the primary screen and manually move/resize the stage:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

stage.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GraphicsEnvironment class to get the size of the screen with/without the taskbar:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
System.out.println("Screen Bounds: " + bounds );

GraphicsDevice screen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration config = screen.getDefaultConfiguration();
System.out.println("Screen Size  : " + config.getBounds());
```

Comment: I can't... I couldn't resist to upvote :) Even though I am looking for JavaFX, this answer works so well! Classy answers like this deserve better recognition and hats off to you dude!

Comment: `Even though I am looking for JavaFX` - your example showed code for a JFrame which is Swing. Please make sure you use the proper tags and post proper code so we can better understand your question.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to put down people?  We only have a limited time to spend answering questions. We want to spend the time wisely helping with questions we think we know the answer to. I was simply asking you to be careful in the future. Also, you were asked to clarify whether the question was for Swing or JavaFX and you replied "any will do". Then later you state "I am looking for JavaFX". Be consistent with your comments. It has nothing to do with being superior. It has to do with respecting people that volunteer time to help others.

Comment: I wouldn't argue with that. Thanks for the advice again. I'll keep it in mind from now on. But the fact that you DID answer one of my questions makes your comments senseless anyway, but yes I will be more specific next time. Good day.